# Adding two objective function with weight in CPLEX

Tags: c++, cplex

in my math model, I have two objective functions which based on its importance I want to allocate weight to them and add them together as one objective function.
here are my two Objectives added together with weight:

```
IloExpr objExpression(env);
for (cc = 0; cc < NumberOfCourses; cc++)
    for (ww = 0; ww < AvailableWeeks; ww++) {
        objExpression += Weight * Diff[cc][ww]; // objective a
    }

for (cc = 0; cc < NumberOfCourses; cc++) {
    objExpression += (1 - Weight) * (M[cc] * Students[cc]); // objective b
}
IloObjective theObjective(env, objExpression, IloObjective::Minimize);
mod.add(theObjective);
objExpression.end();
```

i have set the parameters and variables as follow:

```
const int NumberOfCourses = 15;
const int AvailableWeeks = 8;
const float Weight = 0.5;
double Students[NumberOfCourses];

IloNumVarArray2 Diff(env, NumberOfCourses);
for (cc = 0; cc < NumberOfCourses; cc++)
    Diff[cc] = IloNumVarArray(env, AvailableWeeks, 0.0, 8);

IloNumVarArray M(env, NumberOfCourses);
```

when I run the code it freezes and sets the breakpoint at the second objective line.
also, what should I do if I wanted to have two separate objectives and get output for both individually?

Comment: How is `M` declared? What values does it show for the variables at the breakpoint?

Comment: actually i think the problem is how i set the variable M[cc] but i dont know how to fix it or to see what values it getting now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference documentation of the [IloNumVarArray(env, IloInt)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloNumVarArray.html#method_IloNumVarArray) constructor. It says

> This constructor creates an extensible array of n numeric variables in
> env. Initially, the n elements are empty handles.

In other words, all elements in the newly created array will be NULL (note that this is different from the `IloBoolVarArray` constructor which creates an array in which all elements are new variables). Thus `M` is an array of empty handles in your case.

In order to fix you code you either have to initialize the elements of the array one by one or use a constructor that initializes the variables, like for example

```
IloNumVarArray M(env, NumberOfCourses, 0, IloInfinity);
```

Additionally, I suggest that you compile your code in debug mode without `NDEBUG` being defined. If you compile without `NDEBUG` then many of the functions in Concert will raise an exception if you use empty handles.

If you want to have separate objectives then your problem becomes a multi-objective problem. You may want to read the respective chapter in the user manual and also refer to the `ilodiet.cpp` example that ships with CPLEX.